# Launch Jupyter Notebook on ec2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I’m trying to install Anaconda, Python 3 and Jupyter notebooks on an AWS EC2 instance.  I’m running Ubuntu on the instance.  I’ve installed Python using Anaconda.  I’ve set the default Python to the Anaconda version.  I created a Jupyter notebook config file.  In the Jupyter notebook config file I added:

```
c = get_config()

# Notebook config this is where you saved your pem cert
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' 
# Run on all IP addresses of your instance
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
# Don't open browser by default
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  
# Fix port to 8888
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

I also created a directory for the certs using the code below:

```
mkdir certs
cd certs

sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

But when I try to run Jupiter notebook with the command below:

jupyter notebook

I get the error message below.  My end goal is to be able to launch Jupiter notebook on the AWS EC2 instance and then connect to it remotely in a browser on my laptop.  Does anyone know what my issue might be?

Error:

```
Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'allow_remote_access'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 864, in _default_allow_remote
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1630, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1378, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 159, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 252, in init_settings
    allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 867, in _default_allow_remote
    for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start the jupyter server using the following command:-

```
jupyter notebook --ip=*
```

If you want to keep it running even after the terminal is closed then use:-

```
nohup jupyter notebook --ip=* > nohup_jupyter.out&
```

Remember to open the port 8888 in the AWS EC2 security group inbound to Anywhere (0.0.0.0/0, ::/0)

Then you can access jupyter using http://:8888

Hope this helps. This just a one liner solution!!

Comment: It was ok for me! tks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your AWS instance security group and then configure inbound security group like this below screenshot:

[image: Inbound security group AWS instance configuration]

If you are sure that AWS is configured correctly for permissions, check if your network is not blocking the outbound traffic. You could try to do port tunneling when SSHing into your instance by doing:

ssh -i   -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888

then you can access jupyter locally by going to localhost:8888 on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

In the Jupyter notebook config file that you have shared in the question above a few lines seem to be missing.

To configure the jupyter config file thoroughly, follow these steps:

```
cd ~/.jupyter/

vi jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

[image]

Insert this at the *beginning* of the document:

```
c = get_config()
# Kernel config
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'  # if you want plotting support always in your notebook
# Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' #location of your certificate file
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  #so that the ipython notebook does not opens up a browser by default
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:98ff0e580111:12798c72623a6eecd54b51c006b1050f0ac1a62d'  #the encrypted password we generated above
# Set the port to 8888, the port we set up in the AWS EC2 set-up
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Once you enter these above lines, make sure you **save** the config file before you exit the vi editor!
And also, most importantly remember to replace sha1:98ff0e580111:12798c72623a6eecd54b51c006b1050f0ac1a62d with your password!

Note that since in the above config file we have given port as 8888, the same is added in the security group. (Custom TCP type,TCP protocol, port range as 8888 and source is custom)

Now you are good to go!

Type the following command:

```
screen
```

This command will allow you to create a separate screen for just your Jupyter process logs while you continue to do other work on the ec2 instance.

And now start the jupyter notebook by typing the command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

To visit the jupyter notebook from the browser in your local machine:

Your EC2 instance will have a long url, like this:

ec2-52-39-239-66.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Visit that URL in you browser locally. Make sure to have https at the beginning and port 8888 at the end as shown below.

https://ec2-52-39-239-66.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/